# Add horizontal lines between horizontal list items, possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    margin: 0em 2em;

    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish what I have in that picture, with code.
Not the borders or text but the lines in between the menu items.
I have tried a few ways including making a div but I can't seem to get the styling right. 
If anybody has a solution they've used before I would love to hear it.
Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Edit the question please. Let there be code...

Comment: I just didn't think code was needed. It's just a simple horizontal list with borders on the items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:after` :pseudo-element to add the line. To filter out the last `div` you could use `#container .box:not(:last-child)` selector, which will select all `.box`es but the last one.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
#container .box:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
#container .box:not(:last-child):after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -50%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">Link 1</div>
  <div class="box">Link 2</div>
  <div class="box">Link 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that's perfect, thank you very much for your quick response!

Comment: Based on this solution, slightly improved: http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/tvqkLccy/ (why use negative right?) but no substantial changes

Comment: @AlexPakka - There is nothing wrong with using **negative right**.

Comment: I found your solution extremely robust, the best I saw of the type, and it is perfectly valid. Just wanted to understand the reason behind negative right - there is nothing wrong with it per se.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-item">LINK 1</div>
<div class="menu-line"></div>
<div class="menu-item">LINK 2</div>
<div class="menu-line"></div>
<div class="menu-item">LINK 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-item, .menu-line {
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-line {
    width: 25px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vqm7oawq/

Answer (score 0):

In case of table, you have to do it in a different way. Here's the how. (as you did not specify what you were looking for)

http://jsfiddle.net/3ndwnohn/1/

```css
table tr td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
}
td.space {
    padding:10px;
    border: 0;
}
td.space::before {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -12px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #444;
    content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>numberOne</td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td>numberTwo</td>
        <td class="space"></td>
        <td>numberThree</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```